# USRP : How do I solve a "Timeout while streaming" error

Tags: timeout, usrp

I am trying to capture samples from an USRP X310 using uhd 4.0.0 on fedora 34.
I keep having issues with "timeout" that interrupt streaming instantaneously but I found no reason for this and also no help on the internet ...
I give you the detailed code below.

Thanks for your help !

PS : I have the same results with ./rx_samples_to_file without parameter

```
[user@computer examples]$ ./rx_samples_to_file --freq=1000000000 --bw=500000 --rate 200000  --duration=0.5 --file=x310_test.bin

Creating the usrp device with: ...
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 11.0.1 20210324 (Red Hat 11.0.1-0); Boost_107500; UHD_4.0.0.0-0-unknown
[INFO] [X300] X300 initialization sequence...
[INFO] [X300] Maximum frame size: 1472 bytes.
[INFO] [X300] Radio 1x clock: 200 MHz
Using Device: Single USRP:
  Device: X-Series Device
  Mboard 0: X310
  RX Channel: 0
    RX DSP: 0
    RX Dboard: A
    RX Subdev: TwinRX RX0
  RX Channel: 1
    RX DSP: 1
    RX Dboard: A
    RX Subdev: TwinRX RX1
  RX Channel: 2
    RX DSP: 2
    RX Dboard: B
    RX Subdev: Unknown (0xffff) - 0
  TX Channel: 0
    TX DSP: 0
    TX Dboard: B
    TX Subdev: Unknown (0xffff) - 0

Setting RX Rate: 0.200000 Msps...
Actual RX Rate: 0.200000 Msps...

Setting RX Freq: 1000.000000 MHz...
Setting RX LO Offset: 0.000000 MHz...
Actual RX Freq: 1000.000000 MHz...

Setting RX Bandwidth: 0.500000 MHz...
Actual RX Bandwidth: 0.500000 MHz...

Waiting for "lo_locked": ++++++++++ locked.

Press Ctrl + C to stop streaming...
Timeout while streaming

Done!
```

I also tried benchmark function but it ended the same :

EDIT : I stopped firewalld.services

```
[usr@computer examples]$ ./benchmark_rate --args="type=x300,addr=192.168.10.2,serial=320179E" --channels 0,1 --rx_rate 2e6 --duration 5

[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 11.0.1 20210324 (Red Hat 11.0.1-0); Boost_107500; UHD_4.0.0.0-0-unknown
[00:00:00.000390] Creating the usrp device with: type=x300,addr=192.168.10.2,serial=320179E...
[INFO] [X300] X300 initialization sequence...
[INFO] [X300] Maximum frame size: 1472 bytes.
[INFO] [X300] Radio 1x clock: 200 MHz
[WARNING] [RFNOC::GRAPH] One or more blocks timed out during flush!
Using Device: Single USRP:
  Device: X-Series Device
  Mboard 0: X310
  RX Channel: 0
    RX DSP: 0
    RX Dboard: A
    RX Subdev: TwinRX RX0
  RX Channel: 1
    RX DSP: 1
    RX Dboard: A
    RX Subdev: TwinRX RX1
  RX Channel: 2
    RX DSP: 2
    RX Dboard: B
    RX Subdev: Unknown (0xffff) - 0
  TX Channel: 0
    TX DSP: 0
    TX Dboard: B
    TX Subdev: Unknown (0xffff) - 0

[00:00:03.664016092] Setting device timestamp to 0...
[INFO] [MULTI_USRP]     1) catch time transition at pps edge
[INFO] [MULTI_USRP]     2) set times next pps (synchronously)
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Attempting to set tick rate to 0. Skipping.
[00:00:04.934122870] Testing receive rate 2.000000 Msps on 2 channels
[00:00:05.85737158] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.185992285] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.286246070] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.386497035] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.486745394] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.587001598] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.687253152] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.787508452] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.887760249] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:05.988013669] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.88264700] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.188520367] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.288770879] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.389026502] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.489276462] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.589533078] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.689791950] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.790041080] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.890288133] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:06.990543703] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.90798580] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.191062617] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.291319218] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.391574410] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.491830205] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.592097982] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.692351705] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.792602183] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.892874187] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
[00:00:07.993127880] Receiver error: ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT, continuing...
O[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
O[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
OO[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
O[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
OO[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
O[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
O[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
OO[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
OO[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
OO[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
OO[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
O[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
OO[WARNING] [0/Radio#0] Cannot process RX-related async message to invalid chan 1
[00:00:10.123329222] Benchmark complete.


Benchmark rate summary:
  Num received samples:     0
  Num dropped samples:      0
  Num overruns detected:    20
  Num transmitted samples:  0
  Num sequence errors (Tx): 0
  Num sequence errors (Rx): 0
  Num underruns detected:   0
  Num late commands:        0
  Num timeouts (Tx):        0
  Num timeouts (Rx):        30


Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is a bit old, but after days of troubleshooting this error, I HAVE to share how I fixed it without having to buy a SFP+ adapter.

In my case, I had a method checking the health and status of the onboard FPGA of the USRP. But, in the python desktop side, we actually checked the status too often, which was causing CPU issus, leading to a timeout and performance loss: Linux was almost usable.

I just had to add a small 0.01s temporisation between two checks, and now it works like a charm with no issues at all. I guess the SFP+ module allows higher speed, which make the 0.01s temporisation useless because we are not cpu bottleneking anymore. But it can still happen in higher speeds.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this is your PC filtering out the network packets containing data. This might be firewall rules, or a strangely configured MTU,  for example.

Other than that:

- `--bw=500000`: No USRP hardware has a frontend filter that can be made that narrow. It usually also wouldn't help anything, so chances are you don't want to specify this at all
- `--rx_rate 2e5` That's really at the least least least end of possible sampling rates. This is rarely useful, you'll see the roll-off of the digital filters, probably. Recommendation: Modern PCs are fast. Use 1e6 as rate, and filter and decimate to whatever rate you need in software.
- `enable_tx_dual_eth=1` omit this. (as it reconfigures networking, this might also solve your issue) I don't see how that makes any sense when your USRP doesn't even have TX daughterboards.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, indeed the tx was a total mistake I didn't notice ^^ I changed bw and rx rate a lot so it wasn't the problem I think. However the first solution you gave me was very useful I think. I tried to remove my firewall using sudo systemctl stop firewalld.services but I still have a timeout issue. I updated the post above with my "new" timeout message.

Comment: Finally I solved my problem by changing ethernet with SFP+. Also I wanted to add that I just got samples within a 500kHz bandwith and it worked very well so I think that --bw 500000 was ok ! :)

Comment: it just doesn't *do* anything; it's ignored, as your hardware doesn't have adjustable analog filters in that bandwidth.